# Efficient method to replace text in file

Tags: python

I have a bunch of large text files (more that 5 million lines each). I have to add a prefix to the line if it contains any of the keywords from a list (6000 keywords).

This is the code I have written:

```
import os

mypath = "D:\\Temp"
files = os.listdir(mypath)

fcounter = 0

for file in files:

    fl = open(mypath + file, 'r')
    lines = fl.readlines() 
    fl.close
    
    fl2 = open("D:\\Temp\\Keys.txt", 'r')
    keys = fl2.readlines()
    
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if i % 100000 == 0:
            print(i)
        for key in keys:
            if line.find(key.strip()) > 3:
                lines[i] = '$' + line
                print(line)
    
    fl = open(mypath + file, 'w')
    
    for line in lines:
        fl.write("".join(line))

    fl.close()
    fl2.close()
    fcounter += 1
    print(f'Processed {fcounter}')
```

This is extremely slow. It takes several hours to process a single text file on my system.
Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Use  `if keyword in f1.read().split('\n'):` Modify it your way

Comment: Have you tried using regular expressions for this? It should be possible to quickly create a regular expression for multiple keywords at a time so that you don't have to iterate through them all. Then you can use the match information to look up the keyword and add the correct prefix to the line. This can be simplified if all the prefixes are the same though

Comment: Also @user15914159's solution only works if the only word in the line is the keyword, but not if it contains any other information.

Comment: You should not need to read the entire file in and work with all the lines along the way. Just `for line in fl:` and write out modified (or not as needed) line out to an output file should do and is likely already going to fare better. Atm you populate a massive list and then iterate over it twice (to manipulate and to write out).
As for matching keys, you are likely better off constructing and compiling a single regexp from those and match each line just once.

Comment: For fast membership testing, convert the list of keywords into a `set`. Afterwards you can use something like `if word in keywords:` for the words in each line of the file (you'll need to split each line into separate words).